# MySQL Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION JSON_EXTRACT does not exist

Tags: mysql, json

I'm trying to use the JSON_EXTRACT function in MySQL, but when I run the query:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('{"username":"Olivia"}', '$.username');
```

I receive the error: `Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION JSON_EXTRACT does not exist`.

I was under the impression `that JSON_EXTRACT` was a MySQL built in function, but was I mistaken? 
If anyone knows how to correct this, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Yes this function is available since `v-5.7` of mysql, you may have a lower version of mysql. Check your mysql version.

Comment: Thanks, I think have "mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.15" and in my settings it shows the following: MySQL Workbench Community (GPL) for Windows version 6.3.7 CE build 1199 (64 bit)

Comment: Hi @AbhikChakraborty I do have same issue as olivia has is there any different function forl MySQL client version: 5.5.52 ?

Comment: @ShashankShah no for mysql 5.5.52 this function is not available and only available since 5.7. I am not sure why Olivia was facing this issue since this function should be available for V-5.7

Comment: @ShashankShah do you any solution for this? i also have lower version

Comment: @jayantrawat https://stackoverflow.com/a/40415814/2667307 As per i searched its supporting in > MYsql 5.7 version only.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems like you are trying to get value from the field that contain object value.

The function JSON_EXTRACT supported from MySQL version 5.7.8

If you want get value from the file that contain object value on MySQL server version <5.7.8, you can use alternative function.

REPLACE(
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('{"username":"Olivia"}', '"username":"', -1), '",', 1),
'\', ''
) AS username

Hope this will be solution for you