# Not able to use JSON_EXTRAXT in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am using XAMPP for Linux 5.6.30 and MySQL version is **10.1.21-MariaDB**

I have one table 'employee'

```
id     data
1     [{"name":"abc","age":"56","dob":"2017-05-15","about":"test"}]
2     [{"name":"xyz","age":"26","dob":"2017-09-20","about":"test"}]
3     [{"name":"pqr","age":"96","dob":"2017-03-05","about":"test"}]
```

Table field **data** contains JSON string.

I want to find name from JSON and my query efforts is

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_employee` WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(data,"$.name") = "abc"

SELECT * FROM `tbl_employee` WHERE data->"$.name" = "abc"
```

but it gives me an error

```
> #1305 - FUNCTION testing.json_extract does not exist
```

I take reference from this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html)

Please give me suggestions regarding this?

Is my database not able to do that OR I have used wrongly?

Comment: I think that storing strings - is not the best idea. You should create additional fields in your table to store `name`, `age` and `about`

Comment: A databse that's crying out to be normalized. Please drop this JSON column

Comment: Thank you for help.This is for demo only. In my real-time project, it is stored a large string of JSON. not like name, age and about like this.But I can show it here, so I have put this demo JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `JSON_EXTRACT` in maria db is available since version 10.2.3,
you can read the documentation [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/json_extract/).

You have to update your maria db installation to use that function.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the version you are using it is not exist for your case (JSON_EXTRACT). If you are work on php, you can use php native function json_decode().

Further can be found here : [Error code 1305](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40415766/mysql-error-code-1305-function-json-extract-does-not-exist-in-mysql-client-ver)