# How to apply filter on JSON format database in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I have a database of a table named '**literature**' in this table there is only one column "**item_details**" having data in JSON format as given below:-

```
{
    "book":[
            {
                "language":"English",
                "author":["Y.Nikhilendra","Paresh Khairnar","Madhabendra Rout"]
            },
            {
                "language":"English",
                "author":["Sai Seetharam Nomula"]
            }
        ],
    "diary":[
            {
                "language":"Hindi",
                "author":["Partha Banerjee"]
            },
            {
                "laguage":"English",
                "author":["Gaurav Pandey"]
            }
        ]
}
```

I want to apply filter option according to **languages** in **CodeIgniter**.
in the controller

```
public function view()
{
    $response = $this->view_model->viewModel( $language);       
}
```

Model:-

```
public function viewModel($language)
{
    $this->db->select(*);
    $this->db->from('literature');
    $this->db->where
    //What would be structure of where clause?
}
```

Comment: Before you're trying to find the CodeIgniter syntax, try and find the raw sql syntax. The json type have some serious limitations. If you have data you need to filter on, json is usually not a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_extract`

```
WHERE(json_extract(json_each.value, '$.email') LIKE '%criteria%');
```

[Reference Link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract)

Edit:

if you see function does not exist then may this answer will help you. [answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40415814/5077564)